How do I center CentralWidget in QMainWindow?
Centering seems easy but I am currently stuck. I cannot center the CentralWidget due to the widget not expanding, but as far as I understand widget in this case should not expand (otherwise my chess tiles would be painted in the middle and ultimately the chessboard widget would contain far more than it should).
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QSCreen>
#include <cmath>

class ChessboardWidget : public QWidget{
public:
    explicit ChessboardWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override{
        this->setPalette(Qt::white);
        this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        QPainter painter(this);

        bool black = true;
        int tileSize = std::ceil(this->height() / 8.0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                int y = i * tileSize;
                int x = j * tileSize;
                painter.fillRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize, black ? Qt::black : Qt::white);
                black = !black;
            }
            black = !black;
        }
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override{
        resize(this->size().height(), this->size().height());

        QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    }
private:
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow() {
        auto *window = new QWidget();
        auto *chess = new ChessboardWidget(window);


        setCentralWidget(chess);
        setWindowTitle("Chessboard Example");
        show();
        setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        this->setPalette(Qt::red);
        this->setAutoFillBackground(true);

    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    MainWindow window;

    return QApplication::exec();
}


I tried using Layouts but in order to work they need to fill the space entirely. Is there any way to center the widget without making another widget that would fill the space and using Layout?

QMainWindow has its own private layout that has limited access and internally manages things on its own. The simplest solution would be to use a standard QWidget as central widget, then a custom QBoxLayout that only manages the chessboard and overrides setGeometry() by manually setting the geometry of the chessboard based on the minimum dimension and the center of the given rect. Just remember to call the base setGeometry() implementation first.

If I understand well, I have to make the next structure: standart Qwidget as central widget that takes the whole space, its children QBoxLayout and ChessWidget where QBoxLayout manages ChessWidget. Correct?

Exactly. Consider that I've seen many attempts in doing chess-like graphics and interactions (or any UI that requires content with fixed aspect ratio and custom elements shown in it), and 99% of the times it's better abandon the classic QWidget/QPainter approach, and use the Graphics View Framework instead. You should also be very careful in calling resize() within a resizeEvent(), especially since you're calling the base implementation after doing that.

Here's a way to do it that always keeps the widget in the center. in the paintEvent method you can use move. This will ensure that you move the widget to the middle. To make it a little clearer, I created another rect (but you don't have to, you can also use tileSize*8 instead of the height/width of the rect -- code style is up to everyone).
But as already written in the comments. With GraphicsView you do a little better with things like this.
Anyway, here is the example:
void ChessboardWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    bool black = true;
    int tileSize = height() < width() ?  std::ceil(height() / 8.0) : std::ceil(width() / 8.0);

    QRect boundingRect = QRect(0,0, tileSize*8, tileSize*8);
    for(int i = boundingRect.y(); i < boundingRect.height() ; i+=tileSize){
        for(int j = boundingRect.x(); j < boundingRect.width() ; j+=tileSize){
            painter.fillRect(j,i,tileSize,tileSize, black ? Qt::black : Qt::white);
            black = !black;
        }
        black = !black;
    }
    move(width()/2 - boundingRect.width()/2,height()/2 - boundingRect.height()/2);

}



Here is another example without move directly via the boundingRect.moveTo. At this point you can use margins if you don't want them directly at the top and bottom, or on the right and left anyway
void ChessboardWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);


    bool black = true;
    int tileSize = height() < width() ?  height() / 8.0 : width() / 8.0;
    QRect boundingRect = QRect(0,0, tileSize*8, tileSize*8);
    boundingRect = boundingRect.marginsRemoved(QMargins(50,50,50,50));

    boundingRect.moveTo(width()/2 - boundingRect.width()/2,height()/2 - boundingRect.height()/2);
    painter.fillRect(boundingRect, Qt::yellow);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8 ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; ++j){
            painter.fillRect(boundingRect.x() + (j*boundingRect.width()/8),
                             boundingRect.y() + (i*boundingRect.height()/8),
                             boundingRect.width()/8,
                             boundingRect.height()/8,
                             black ? Qt::black : Qt::white);
            black = !black;
        }
        black = !black;
    }

    QRect scoreRect = QRect(0, boundingRect.bottom(), width(), height()-boundingRect.height()-50);
    scoreRect = scoreRect.marginsRemoved(QMargins(5,5,5,5));
    painter.fillRect(scoreRect, Qt::magenta);

}



So as you can see, the design is very flexible. In the end you see what suits you best. There are several variants of this.

I would strongly discourage the first approach: while move() doesn't normally cause repainting, there is no absolute way to know that for sure (for instance, a QStyle may call for updates on QEvent::Move events) and may lead to potential recursion. The paintEvent() should always only do what it's expected: painting. Anything else should be done with extreme care (and awareness), especially if it deals with geometry changes. Then, both approaches are controversial in concept: unless the widget is intended for pure painting (no interaction at all), the painting must be consistent »

» with any mouse event handling that would eventually access the board, meaning that many geometry computations have to be duplicated (and therefore, any related change in code logic has to be reflected everywhere else, leading to possible bugs we're not careful enough). A possible alternative would be to use a centralized system managing geometries in relative coordinates, which would then be always translated to widget coordinates whenever required, but that's still prone to issues if not implemented correctly. Using an inner widget properly managed within a layout is certainly easier.

Your thought is correct, but it goes too far. This is a big topic. Just like with performance. Everyone wants to achieve the best possible performance with a for loop (in range 1-10) and combine the most unusual things link. Here is the simple question of how to center. I would prefer your suggestion with GraphicsView over what you have written now (because that just goes too far for this use case)

Nobody expect us to provide the perfect solution (which almost never exists). The point about the first code still remains, though: no geometry change should ever happen within a paintEvent(). Besides, the above only considers coordinates using the whole geometry of the parent, which is inappropriate, as the layout may have other widgets and margins (which is the case of QMainWindow, for instance, when having a menu bar).
